# Add/Remove Class on click

Tags: jquery

I've set up a function like this...

```
$('.trigger').click(function(){
  $('.active').removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

When a user clicks on `.trigger` it adds the class active, but I also need the active class to be removed when a user clicks `.active` again. How would I do it?

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.trigger').click(function(){
     $(this).toggleClass('active');
});
```

Comment: `$(this).toggleClass('active');` will suffice

Answer (score 0):

While looking at the scenario you provided, you must be looking for `.toggleClass()`

Try,

```
$('.trigger').click(function(){
  $('.active').not($(this)).removeClass('active');
  $(this).toggleClass('active');
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/pjU8L/1/)

Comment: @jwinton Have you tried the demo that I have provided.?

Answer (score 0):

For that use this:

```
$('.active').click(function () { // click on active
  $(this).removeClass('active'); // remove class!
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
$('.trigger').click(function(){
    if($(this).hasClass('active')){
        $(this).removeClass('active');
    }else{
      $(this).addClass('active');
    }
});
```

**Alternate code**

```
$('.trigger').click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass( "active" );
});
```

use **[toggleClass()](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/)** jquery function

> Add or remove one or more classes from each element in the set of matched elements, depending on either the class's presence or the value of the switch argument.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('.trigger').click(function(){
  $(this).toggleClass('active').siblings('.trigger').removeClass('active');
});  //---^^^^^^^^^^^-------------toggling the class names are required here.
```

#### [Demo @ Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ngHur/)

Answer (score 0):

It kinda sounds like you're looking for this:

```
$('.trigger').click(function() {
    $(this).addClass('active');
});

$('.active').click(function() {
    $('.trigger').removeClass('active');
});
```

The first click function comes from your statement:

> When a user clicks on .trigger it adds the class active

And the second click function comes from you saying:

> but I also need the active class to be removed when a user clicks .active again.

In this statement, do you mean when a user clicks `.active` or `.trigger`? This solution is based of you meaning `.active`, like your statement suggests.

Hopefully this is helpful!